# Find job status using the id returned from Database.executeBatch?

Tags: apex, batch, asyncapexjob

I have a class that is Database.Batchable which I execute via Database.executeBatch. How do I find the job status Id using the id returned from Database.executeBatch? It doesn't seem to match the Id I get from querying AsyncApexJob. Is there a way to get the status via Apex?

Comment: Did you check the answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/203924/how-to-get-apex-job-id-based-on-future-call)?  It's not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

The ids are truncated on the salesforce ui but you can query it via

SELECT Id, Status, ApexClassID, JobItemsProcessed, TotalJobItems, JobType, CompletedDate, ExtendedStatus
FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = 'id'

Comment: Not sure how this answers your original question - can you update your question?

Comment: Also it would be better to show this as using a binding variable on the assumption you would do this from Apex.